# Not sure how to convert a SQL FullText search query to a Linq to Entities expression

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need help converting a simple SQL contains query to the Linq to Entities equivalent. I'm using EF 4, MVC 4, VS 2012, and SQL 2008. I have a fulltext index created on the table.

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Media WHERE CONTAINS (*, 'cat')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not support full text search. If you were searching just one column you could try using .Contains. In your case you may just want to send the Sql query to the database rather than use Linq as there is no equivalent for the above query.